# Why does Math.floor(Math.random()) function always return "0"?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, random, while-loop, infinite-loop

I am writing a program that chooses a random number between `0` and `1` and then enters a while loop until the random number generator selects a value more than `.5`. Every time I run the program, the program returns `0` and loops infinitely until it crashes. Why is this occurring? Shouldn't `Math.floor(Math.random())` eventually select a number higher than `.5`?

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random());
while(randomNumber < .5) {
var name = prompt("Do you want to play a game? Like checkers or something?");
if (name === "Yes") {
    console.log("Good jorb!");
} else if(name === "No.") {
    console.log("Go away!!!!!");
 else {
    console.log("I have no idea");
}

var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random());
}
```

Comment: I suggest that if you want your post to be taken seriously that you not throw in curse words for no reason.

Comment: The second `var randomNumber = ...` should just be `randomNumber = ...`

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you're trying to achieve overall. I can, however, tell you that the `while` loop will never run as written. `Math.floor` drops a number down to the closest integer. `Math.random` returns a number between 0 and 1, not including 1. That means that `Math.floor(Math.random())` will always be 0, and thus never more than 0.5 as needed to execute anything in your loop.

Comment: If you want to test for different combinations of uppercase and lowercase why not `if (name.toUpperCase() === 'YES')`? If you want to allow for an optional full stop then perhaps a case-insensitve regex: `if (/^(yes|yup)\.?$/i.test(name))` - that single if test would replace *all* of yours...

Comment: I'm trying to make to make it so the confirm prompt will loop at random until math.random selects a number that is more than .5 on a scale from 0 to 1 @DLH

Comment: To clarify, I am trying it so that after the user selects a response and the console.log prints out a response that the prompt will keep appearing until Math.random selects a number greater than .5. @DLH

Comment: Also, I did get rid of Math.floor because I realized that wouldn't make any sense on a scale from 0 to 1. Thank you. @DLH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line almost always return 0 and that is why it does not get into the while.

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random());
```

Math.random() return float values lower than 1 starting from 0 ... and with Math.floor you are getting the int part which indeed is 0

Comment: According to the specification, [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) can return 0 but *never* returns 1.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons:

- `Math.floor(Math.random())`, will always be zero so the loop will never start. `Math.random()` will give a number between 0 and 1 and you are flooring that one that means you are always rounding off down, which means zero.
- If you want the while to stop, it is better to `break;` when the condition is right.

This code will work:

```
var randomNumber = Math.random();
while(randomNumber > .5) {
    var name = prompt("Do you want to play a game? Like checkers or something?");
    if (name === "Yes") {
        console.log("Good jorb!"); break;
    } else if(name === "Nope.") {
        console.log("Okay that is fine.");
    } else {
        console.log("I don't know, man. I don't know");
    }
    randomNumber = Math.random();
}
```

But now it does not just depend on the answer whether the loop will continue but also on `randomNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable randomNumber was already initialized with your first line, to change it's value simply use `randomNumber = newValue` where `newValue` is the value you wish to set it to, using a method or hardcoded value. You do not need to use the `var` keyword again.

Also using `Math.floor` method on `Math.random` will always return 0, as Math.random will return a number between 0 and 1, which will floor to 0.

You were missing the closing bracket on your while loop.

I cleaned you code up a little to chain your if boolean operators, although there are better ways to construct this code.

```
var randomNumber = Math(Math.random());
while(randomNumber > .5) {
    var name = prompt("Do you want to play a game? Like checkers or something?");
    if (name === "Yes" || name === "yes" || name === "Yes." || name === "yes." || name === "Yup" || name === "Yup." || name ===  "yup." || name === "yup")
    {
        console.log("Good jorb!");
    }

    else if(name === "No." || name === "No" || name === "no" || name === "no." || name === "nope" || name === "nope." || name ===  "Nope" || name === "Nope.")
    {
        console.log("That's too bad.");
    }
    else 
    {
        console.log("I don't know, man. I don't know");
    }
    randomNumber = Math(Math.random());
};// Close your while loop.
```

Comment: You're right! I fixed it, was writing in C# code elsewhere while writing this, my apologies and thanks for catching it. Also there are tons of better ways to do it (regex/arrays etc.) as posted above, just used this to keep it in a format easier to understand for the original poster.

Comment: Right, yes, you don't really have to defend yourself at all, especially after you immediately corrected it. I'll delete my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop will never run.  
Math.random() returns a number n where 0 <= n <1 
Math.floor(n) returns n rounded towards zero. 

so your variable randomNumber will always equal zero.

you could also replace your if statements with an array of values to check.
Then look up the index of name in that array.
if the index is -1 it doesn't exist otherwise log "Good jorb!"

```
var randomNumber = Math.random();
while(randomNumber > .5) {
  var name = prompt("Do you want to play a game? Like checkers or something?");
  var yesArray = ["Yes", "yes", "Yes.", "yes.", "Yup", "Yup.", "yup.", "yup"];
  if(yesArray.indexOf(name) == -1) {
    console.log("I don't know, man. I don't know");
  } else {
    console.log("Good jorb!");
  }
  randomNumber = Math.random();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (Sorry if I got any of the counts wrong on the long expletive... there were a lot of them...)

```
while(true){
    var name=prompt("Do you want to play a game? Like checkers or something?");
    if(name.search(/^[yY](es|up)\.?$/)!=-1){
        console.log('Good jorb!');
    }else if(name.search(/^[nN]o(pe)?\.?$/)!=-1){
        console.log('F'+'U'.repeat(12)+'C'.repeat(13)+'K'.repeat(9)+' Y'+'O'.repeat(11)+'U'.repeat(18)+'!'.repeat(12));
    }else{
        console.log("I don't know, man. I don't know");
    }
    if(condition){
        break;
    }
}
```

Just to clarify about the regular expressions:  They essentially look for the different forms of the word with capitalization or no and punctuation or no representing the full word (^ is the beginning of the string and $ is the end of the string).  That should save you a lot of trouble.

Oh, and try to avoid `while(true)` for real development practices.  `for(var i=0;i<2e7;i++)` or something similar is a better practice, but i figure if it's just for command line, that should be fine.